# Converting single-thread app to ASyncTask app

Tags: android

I am creating a simple RSS reader which displays headlines in ListView, downloading it from the .xml file of specified website.

I wrote the app and it works on the single thread, but i want to use ASyncTask so that all the downloading happens in the background and the UI don't hang.

Now, i have never used AsyncTask before, and i googled it but still i'm not sure where to transfer the methods of my code to which ASyncTask methods. Please help me do it.

**SimpleRssReaderActivity.java**

```
package mohit.app.rssreader;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class SimpleRssReaderActivity extends ListActivity {
    List headlines;
    List links;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

     // Initializing instance variables arrays
        headlines = new ArrayList();
        links = new ArrayList();

        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://feeds.pcworld.com/pcworld/latestnews");

            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
            XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

                //  get the XML from an input stream
            xpp.setInput(getInputStream(url), "UTF_8");


            boolean insideItem = false;

                // Returns the type of current event: START_TAG, END_TAG, etc..
            int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) 
            {
                    if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) 
                {

                    if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) 
                    {
                        insideItem = true;
                    } 
                    else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) 
                    {
                        if (insideItem)
                            headlines.add(xpp.nextText()); //extract the headline
                    } 
                    else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")) 
                    {
                        if (insideItem)
                            links.add(xpp.nextText()); //extract the link of article
                    }
                }
                else if(eventType==XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item"))
                {
                    insideItem=false;
                }

                eventType = xpp.next(); //move to next element
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Binding data
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, headlines);

        setListAdapter(adapter);



    }

public InputStream getInputStream(URL url) {
   try {
       return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
   } catch (IOException e) {
       return null;
     }
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
   Uri uri = Uri.parse((String) links.get(position));
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
   startActivity(intent);
}


}
```

SO thats my whole code, tell me which new methods to create and the codes to transfer in that method. THNX!

Comment: Well you want HTTP part to run on seperate thread right??

Comment: Well to many answers already :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

       InitTask _initTask = new InitTask();
        _initTask.execute( this );

}
```

some thing like this ......

```
/**
     * sub-class of AsyncTask
     */
    protected class InitTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, ArrayList>
    {
        // -- run intensive processes here
        // -- notice that the datatype of the first param in the class definition matches the param passed to this method 
        // -- and that the datatype of the last param in the class definition matches the return type of this method
                @Override
                protected String doInBackground( Context... params ) 
                {

                        return inBackground();
                }

                // -- gets called just before thread begins
                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() 
                {
                        Log.i( "makemachine", "onPreExecute()" );
                        super.onPreExecute();

                }

                // -- called from the publish progress 
                // -- notice that the datatype of the second param gets passed to this method
                @Override
                protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) 
                {
                        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
                        Log.i( "makemachine", "onProgressUpdate(): " +  String.valueOf( values[0] ) );
                }

                // -- called if the cancel button is pressed
                @Override
                protected void onCancelled()
                {
                        super.onCancelled();
                        Log.i( "makemachine", "onCancelled()" );

                }

                // -- called as soon as doInBackground method completes
                // -- notice that the third param gets passed to this method
                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute( ArrayList result ) 
                {
                        super.onPostExecute(result);
                        Log.i( "makemachine", "onPostExecute(): " + result );
              // Binding data
                 ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result );

                   SimpleRssReaderActivity.this.setListAdapter(adapter);

                }
    }    
 private ArrayList inBackground(){


// Initializing instance variables arrays
        headlines = new ArrayList();
        links = new ArrayList();

        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://feeds.pcworld.com/pcworld/latestnews");

            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
            XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

                //  get the XML from an input stream
            xpp.setInput(getInputStream(url), "UTF_8");


            boolean insideItem = false;

                // Returns the type of current event: START_TAG, END_TAG, etc..
            int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) 
            {
                    if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) 
                {

                    if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) 
                    {
                        insideItem = true;
                    } 
                    else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) 
                    {
                        if (insideItem)
                            headlines.add(xpp.nextText()); //extract the headline
                    } 
                    else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")) 
                    {
                        if (insideItem)
                            links.add(xpp.nextText()); //extract the link of article
                    }
                }
                else if(eventType==XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item"))
                {
                    insideItem=false;
                }

                eventType = xpp.next(); //move to next element
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

     return headlines ;


}
```

this example is as per your code but if possible i would like to give some suggestion not must but should use

1-  creating and setting the adapter work should remain in Oncreate just set the empty Array list there and pass that list to Asytask  (in constructor ) and fill the data in same and just call in notify data set changed in onPostExecute.

Comment: k..so i just define contectview in onCreate,close it. Then write InitTask class for the process? right?

Answer (score 2):

Well I don't really know what methods you want to do in the async task, but basically you use this model here

```
public class PostTask extends AsyncTask<Void/*what the doInBackground method wants*/, String/* What the onProgress method wants*/, Boolean /*What the doInBackground method returns*/> {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            boolean result = false;

            //All your code goes in here 

            //If you want to do something on the UI use progress update

            publishProgress("progress");
            return result;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 1; i < progress.length; i++) {
                    str.append(progress[i] + " ");
                }

        }
    }
```

You want to do all your networking tasks in an async task :D

Answer (score 0):

Everything goes in doInBackground except the part where you update the UI by creating the adapter and setting it.  That goes in onPostExecute.

Answer (score 0):

For each application in android there is one main thread called UI thread. And if you do all the time taking tasks in the UI thread your application may not respond well and it leads to force close some time. To avoid this kind of problems you have to use Async Task.
I reccomend you to go through [Process&Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) where they have explained how to handle time taking tasks in back ground. You have to subclass AsyncTask and and implement the doInBackground() callback method to do long tasks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a class for your Asynch task

   EXAMPLE:   MyActivity.java =>

   ```
   public class MyActivity extends MyBaseActivity {
     ...
     MyDownloaderTask downloaderTask = null;
     ...

     public void onCreate (Bundl savedInstanceState) {
       ...
       downloaderTask = new MyDownloaderTask ();
       ...
     }
   }

   private class MyDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<Object, String, Boolean> {
     ...
     @Override
     protected void onPreExecute () {
       ...
   ```
2. Move your XML methods into your new "downloader" class as appropriate.

   My guess is you'll just cut/paste everything into an override of "doInBackground()"
3. Here's a good tutorial:

   - http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html

   <= Look down to "5. Tutorial: AsyncTask"

'Hope that helps